# View hidden not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am adding loader in one view.it working fine first time.
when i m calling on second time on this view. my loader not shown.

```
loader=[[Loader alloc]initWithNibName:@"Loader" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:loader.view];
loader.view.hidden=YES;

-(void)myMethod
 {
   [loader.view setHidden:NO];       
 }
```

Comment: Do you check that multiple loader view added in view when you come second time that same code run again.

Comment: @NitinGohel  i am call my method second time on button click on same view. and my method call

Comment: but ther is already view added why you added again by second time ?

Comment: where do you add loader view on view? and try to just set loader.hidden=YES / NO

Comment: i m added on viewdidload

Comment: @NitinGohel itis not working

Comment: Varun, you can try [loader.view setNeedsDisplay]; or [self.view setNeedsDisplay];. This will redraw your loader.view which might resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the frame of the view Like this:

```
loader.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

The view maybe visible but with Zero frame

Comment: that view load from XIB so i dont think there is need to setting frame.

Comment: This code is horribly wrong - it will fail as soon as self.view.frame.origin is something other than (0,0). In cases like this, you need to use the superview's **bounds**, not frame, because the view's frames are in different coordinate systems.

Comment: Yes Daniel you are right, my concern was in the size of frame not the origin. will update it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try a different approach. With views like these, I would make the loader as a singleton. Then have 2 class methods. There are many sources on how to create a singleton. This would make it a lot easier to reuse in other controllers too.

```
+ (void)showInView:(UIView *)displayView {
// get shared instance and add as subview to displayView
}

+ (void)dissmissView {
// get shared instance and remove from superview
}
```